# Code for checking leap year and counting no of days in a month

Tags: python, if-statement

This is my code:

```
def cal(month):
    if month in ['January', 'march','may','july','august','oct','dec']:
       print ("this month has 31 days")
    elif month in ['april','june','sept','nov']:
       print ("this month has 30 days")
    elif month == 'feb' and leap(year)== True:
       print ("this month has 29 days")
    elif month == 'feb' and leap(year) == False:
        print ("this month has 28 days")
    else:
        print ("invalid input")   


def leap(year):
    if (year % 4== 0) or (year % 400 == 0):
       print ("its a leap year!")
    else: 
       print ("is not a leap year")

year = int(input('type a year: '))
print ('you typed in :' , year)
month = str(input('type a month: '))
print ('you typed in :', month)



cal(month)
leap(year)
```

The output I'm receiving:

```
type a year: 2013
you typed in : 2013
type a month: feb
you typed in : feb
is not a leap year
is not a leap year
invalid input
is not a leap year
```

Why am I not getting the output for count of days in feb if it is a 28 day month or 29?

Why am I getting the invalid input part even though its an else?

Comment: The return value of `leap` is `None`. Both `None == True` and `None == False` are false.

Comment: 1900 was not a leap year.  Your test would assume it was.

Comment: thanks mate. solved it. :)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  isnt 1900 a leap year?

Comment: @user4789833 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm

Comment: No — 1900 was not a leap year, and 2100 won't be either.  A leap year is either divisible by 400, or it is not divisible by 100 but is divisible by 4.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to return a True or False in your leap(year) function for it to work correctly.

This is with the leap year algorithm from Wikipedia.

```
def leap(year):
    if year % 400 == 0:
        return True
    if year % 100 == 0:
        return False
    if year % 4 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Check out this comment by [Jon Leffler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978182/code-for-checking-leap-year-and-counting-no-of-days-in-a-month#comment57685751_34978182)

Comment: Changed the algorithm :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to use your own function to replace basics one. Python has module to manage dates. You should use it.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange

```
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.monthrange(2002,1)
(1, 31)
```

And for leap year, still in doc :

```
https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.isleap
```

Regarding your code, your function `leap` should return a boolean since you use it in a condition statement, otherwise `leap(whatever) == true` will always return false.

Comment: Problem is, the author is trying to do something he shouldn't do the way he's doing it.

Comment: True, but when that's the case, your answer should explain that, and usually still explain what's wrong with the code.

Comment: You're right. I've edited my answer to be more friendly and educative.

Comment: i am aware of the module , i was trying to write a longer code to get some practice in looping, and as a beginner just want to create something from scratch. thanks for your help anyway.:) appreciated.